# Java ArrayList: check if an id is in the list

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble solving this basic problem in Java. I have an array of 5 animal cages, each cage has an ID.
When I try to verify if a cage already contains an animal in it, the check works only for the first 2 cages, anything after that is buggy.

this is the main:

```
    Cat picasso = new Cat ("Cat", "Picasso");
    Cat athena = new Cat("Cat", "Athena");
    Dog thunder = new Dog ("Dog", "Thunder");
    Dog buffy = new Dog("Dog", "Buffy");

    Pets store = new Pets("Super store");

    store.addToCage(buffy, 1);
    store.addToCage(athena, 1);
```

this throws an error message as it should: "cage is full"

but this one does not:

```
    store.addToCage(buffy, 1);
    store.addToCage(athena, 2);
    store.addToCage(thunder, 2);
```

It prints the message (cage is full) but it still adds the animal in cage 2. anything more than 2 cages is problematic: it prints the 3rd cage twice for example.

here is the method addToCage in the class Pets:

```
     class Pets {

        ArrayList<Cage> cages = new ArrayList<Cage>();

     public void addToCage(Animal animal, int cageId){
       int nbrCages = cages.size();
       Cage tmp, cage;

       if(nbrCages == 0){
           cage = new Cage(cageId);
           cage.setAnimal(animal);
           this.cages.add(cage);
       }else{

            for(int i=0; i < nbrCages; i++){
                tmp = cages.get(i);
                if(tmp.getId() == cageId){

                System.out.println("cage is full");
                }else{
                    cage = new Cage(cageId);
                    cage.setAnimal(animal);
                    this.cages.add(cage);
```

This is the method that prints the results:

```
    public String displayResults(){
        String results="";
        int nbrCages = cages.size();

        if(nbrCages > 0){
           Cage tmp;
           for(int i=0; i < nbrCages; i++){
             tmp = cages.get(i);
             results += tmp.showCages();
         }

       }else{
       results += "store is empty"; 
    }

       return results;
   }
```

Comment: Any reason to use an `ArrayList` and not a `HashMap` ?

Comment: so you don;t wanna add animals if `cages` size if 2?

Comment: @PseudoAj : I want to solve it using an ArrayList. part of the requirement

Comment: @Deadpool  basically to add an animal into a cage, the cage must be empty. The way to check this is by looking into the cage ID. unless there is another way

Comment: okay i got you but what if cage already has 2 animals and you are trying add third one which is not there in cage? @omar

Comment: what does this `showCages` do? @omar

Comment: @Deadpool showCages prints the id of the cage and the name of the animal in it. To answer your first question: a cage cannot contain more than one animal in it

Comment: `a cage cannot contain more than one animal in it` which mean size should not be >1 right? @omar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `else` statement.
You should do a verification like this:

```
public void addToCage(Animal animal, int cageId) {
    int nbrCages = cages.size();
    Cage tmp, cage;

    if (nbrCages == 0) {
        cage = new Cage(cageId);
        cage.setAnimal(animal);
        this.cages.add(cage);
    } else {

        boolean cageInUse = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < nbrCages; i++) {
            tmp = cages.get(i);
            if (tmp.getId() == cageId) {
                System.out.println("cage is full");
                cageInUse = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!cageInUse) {
            cage = new Cage(cageId);
            cage.setAnimal(animal);
            this.cages.add(cage);
        }
    }
}
```

This is not the best solution, but it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much Rhuan Karlus. It works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem you are just checking cage is empty or not `nbrCages == 0` but not cage has space or not.

If animal presents `tmp.getId() == cageId` you are just printing `cage is full` change it to `animal is present in cage`

```
public void addToCage(Animal animal, int cageId){
   int nbrCages = cages.size();
   Cage tmp, cage;

   if(nbrCages < 2){     // First check the cage have space or not

    for(int i=0; i < nbrCages; i++){
            tmp = cages.get(i);
            if(tmp.getId() == cageId){     // Now check animal present in cage or not, if present don't add

            System.out.println(" Animal already present in cage ");
            }else{                          // If not present the add the animal to cage
                cage = new Cage(cageId);
                cage.setAnimal(animal);
                this.cages.add(cage);     
   }else{    // If not print cage is full

        System.out.println(" cage is full on animals ");
    }
```